# Per-site "hot meta questions" are still hot after being deleted

Tags: bug, status-completed, per-site-meta, community-bulletin

I often click on the questions in the "Hot Meta Posts" section of the sidebar. Today when I clicked on one of the questions I noticed that it had already been deleted.

[image: Deleted question showing in "Hot Meta Posts"]
[image: Question from sidebar link not found]

I view this as a bug, though you could also view it as a feature request I suppose. I do not think that a deleted Meta question should still be considered "hot".

Comment: Caching, it's always to blame.

Comment: The bug is in the community bulletin algorithm, which is not checking the question status.

Comment: Caching indeed. The bulletins are cached for a good while.

Comment: @Oded 20 minutes, as the answer says, right?

Comment: An hour, if I'm reading the code right, @Sha

Comment: @Oded: I believe I based my 20 minutes on information found here on Meta somewhere. An hour feels awfully long given my own experience with the CB.

Comment: @Oded: see [Can the threshold for what makes it into the Community Bulletin be raised?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252467)

Comment: @Oded: could it be that 20 minutes is a Stack Overflow specific timeout and 1 hour is for the rest of the network?

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, since it's MSE better have full answer, if Oded confirms better add this to your answer as well.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: absolutely.

Comment: Not from what I can see. And it looks like the cache has always been 1 hour, @Martijn

Comment: @Oded: interesting, I'll go and time the CB changes on Stack Overflow for a while then, because I was sure I observed the 20 minutes window in action. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters - there is some invalidation logic - so it might not be a hard 1 hour.

Comment: @Oded: right; presumably that it'll re-cache once every hour, but something *else* invalidates every 20 minutes?

Comment: Checked - invalidation only happens when changes to community events occur (adding, updating, deleting), @MartijnPieters

Comment: @Oded: I wonder where Shog got the 20 minutes idea from then. Is there a slider somewhere that is being ignored here then?

Comment: I don't know where that came from - there are setting for number and types of posts to show there, but the cache timeout is hard coded (3600 seconds), @MartijnPieters

Comment: @Oded: Check, rolled back my edit back to Shadow's change, poked Shog9 on the issue.

Answer (score 7):

The bulletin is updated once every hour. It'll be gone soon enough.

The community bulletin is aggressively cached because it has to appear on a **lot** of pages, across both the child-Meta and the main site. As this (a hot Meta post being outright deleted) only happens *rarely*, I don't see any reason to complicate the caching.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. Eventual consistency and ROI.

Comment: Delete justifies updating the cache in my opinion. The questions list is also "heavy" and cached, but deletion cause instant removal from the list, even before the cache expires.

Comment: @Shadow: that's not true; I see deleted questions on a regular basis. It *may* be possible that the cache can be invalidated, but that'd mean that every deletion then needs to test for 'inclusion in the bulletin' at that moment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters are you sure? You probably see deleted *answers*, which are still linked from questions lists.

Comment: @Shadow: I  absolutely sure, yes. Spam, manual self-deletion, deletion by community voting all can lead to a *delay* before the post is removed from the question list. It is not instant.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I rolled back your edit for now, pending confirmation from Oded that [Shog9 is wrong](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252465/can-the-threshold-for-what-makes-it-into-the-community-bulletin-be-raised/252467#252467) or that Stack Overflow has special treatment.

Comment: True, while @Shog9 is the big boss, Oded can see the actual code. :)

Answer (score 5):

The functionality for this [has been updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353492/hot-meta-posts-allow-for-mod-removal-and-thoughts-about-future-improvements) so that a meta post on Hot Meta Posts will be immediately removed from the community bulletin on the associated main site, upon deletion of the meta post.

---

> meta post so hot.
> but it had to go; trash it!
> gone from bulletin