# How long does it take to update my “Hot Meta Post up-vote” in home page?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, community-bulletin

I have up-voted a question in Meta Webmasters Stackexchange. That question is available in home page under Hot Meta Post list. But my count has not been updated. Why it’s not updating quickly? If it will take time means what’s the approximate time duration?

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> Why it’s not updating quickly?

The script that determines the Hot Meta Posts is quite expensive, and will take some time to run. That is the reason the posts and their score is cached. Also, it isn't that important to update it very frequent, since there usually aren't that much posts on meta.

> If it will take time means what’s the approximate time duration?

The update window for the Hot Meta Posts bulletin seems to be [an hour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236687/per-site-hot-meta-questions-are-still-hot-after-being-deleted#comment827699_236687).

Comment: Whoops, hour - either it was changed, or the answer author just guessed. Oded gave official response in a comment.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I see. Edited.